# does "find -name " matches the whole path or just the basename?

Tags: linux, find, pattern-matching

I was getting inconsistent results with pattern matching using -name, -iname, especially when looking for files `-type f` or directories `type -d`. Can someone explain under which circumstances -name matches the whole path vs basename?

Comment: IMO the documentation is quite clear, the basename of the current pathname matters. If you show us ([edit] the question) the commands leading to the inconsistent results, plus the results, plus your expectations, then probably we will be able to tell where the problem really is. Is `-o` involved?